# Moving a large dataset from the PS to PL on a zynq device?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado, ddr, zynq

I am at the moment trying to interface with DRAM on my Xilinx Zynq device such that I am capable of moving a large amount of data from the processing system (PS) side to the programmable logic (PL).  The size of the data is around 3 mb, for which it most likely is the dram i have to interface.

The examples i've found on the net seem to usually tackle this problem by either sending 32 bits multiple times back and forth, which just seems a bit inefficient.

How do I possible most effectively send a large dataset from the PS to PL?

[image]

Comment: Do you realize that it may only be you that understands what "ps", "dr", "pl" and "zynq" mean??  You are far more likely to get some answers if you were to generalize your question and spell out more clearly what these things mean.

Comment: Ahh.. sorry..  Hope  the edits makes it a bit more understandable..

Comment: A block diagram would help. Note that interfacing to an external DRAM still involves moving bits back and forth in chunks, just that they're more likely to be 64 or 128 bit chunks.

Comment: ... Couldn't the data be written to some specific memory address, and such that the PL only reads the data from those address?

Comment: Thus utilize the full memory of the dram rather that part of it.. 32 bit..

Comment: This question is far too broad to answer in its present form. There are many ways to transfer data between the CPU(s) and the programmable logic of a Zynq FPGA, and the correct method depends very much on the application -- particularly the *timing* of when the data is available, how long it takes the logic to process the data and when the results are needed.

Comment: The application... The Fpga contains a vga driver which display bit matrix on to the screen.  The CPU is the one creating this matrix, and therefore it should transfer it to the PL part and thus the vga IP..

Answer (score 1):

The interconnect between the Processing System and Programmable Logic is limited by the bus width of the AXI interface.

It sound like you are looking for a way of passing a buffer directly from software to the PL all in one go, rather than individual write operations. If this is the case I would suggest looking into using the Direct Memory Access (DMA) IPs provided by Xilinx. They should allow you to segment off a subset of the PS RAM and access it directly from the PL.

Comment: Yes.. Exactly.. but haven't found any documentations that addresses this issue...

Comment: Perhaps this example project for the ZYBO would be helpful. https://github.com/Digilent/ZYBO/tree/master/Projects/hdmi_out

It uses the VDMA to pass data from linux out HDMI and VGA.